# How to use refreshApex on Parent Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, refresh, parent-to-child, refreshapex

what i am trying to achieve is, when i edit an account to active = 'Yes'.
My LWC component show refresh dynamically and show that active account when i click show active accounts button, but its not showing unless i refresh the whole page. How to refresh just my LWC component?? Used refreshApex but not working

Parent.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Accounts" icon-name="custom:custom42">

        <lightning-button variant="brand" label={clickedButtonLabel} title="show Active" onclick={handleActiveClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small">
        </lightning-button>

        <lightning-button variant="brand" label={clickedButtonLabel1} title="Show Inactive" onclick={handleInactiveClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small">
        </lightning-button>
    
    </lightning-card>

    <div class="space"></div>

         <!-- include Parent to child and child to parent communication--> 
        <template if:true={boolVisible}> 
            <lightning-card title="Active Accounts" icon-name="standard:action_list_component">
            <c-child-account-active-or-inactive onviewcaseclicked={handleCaseView} child-active-account={activeAccount} >
            </c-child-account-active-or-inactive>
        </lightning-card> 
        </template>

         <!-- include Parent to child and child to parent communication--> 
         <template if:true={boolVisible1}> 
            <lightning-card title="Inactive Accounts" icon-name="standard:action_list_component">
            <c-child-account-active-or-inactive onviewcaseclicked={handleCaseView} child-inactive-account={inactiveAccount} >
            </c-child-account-active-or-inactive>
        </lightning-card> 
        </template>
```

Parent JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountManipulation.getAccounts';
import getAccountCase from '@salesforce/apex/AccountManipulation.getAccountCase';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

const column = [
    {
        label: 'Case Number',
        fieldName: 'CaseNumber',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Case Status',
        fieldName: 'Status',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
];

export default class ParentAccountActiveOrInactive extends LightningElement {
    @track columns=column;
    activeAccount;
    inactiveAccount;

    @track clickedButtonLabel = 'Show Active';
    @track clickedButtonLabel1 = 'Show Inactive';
    @track boolVisible=false;
    @track boolVisible1=false;

    @wire(getAccounts) accDetails({error, data}){
        if(data){
            console.log('Data =',data);
           this.activeAccount = data.filter(i=> i.Active__c == 'Yes');
           
           this.inactiveAccount = data.filter(i=> i.Active__c == 'No');
           
           console.log("active accounts:",this.activeAccount);
           console.log("inactive accounts:",this.inactiveAccount);
        }

        if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.activeAccount = undefined;
            this.inactiveAccount = undefined;
        }
    }
    
    handleActiveClick(event){
        const label = event.target.label;
        console.log('Label :',label);

        if(label === 'Show Active'){
            this.clickedButtonLabel = 'Hide Active';
            this.boolVisible = true;
            refreshApex(this.activeAccount);////Not working when edited a record to active
        }
        else if(label === 'Hide Active'){
            this.clickedButtonLabel = 'Show Active';
            this.boolVisible = false;
            this.caseNumber = Null;
        }
    }

    handleInactiveClick(event){
        const label = event.target.label;

        if(label === 'Show Inactive'){
            
            this.clickedButtonLabel1 = 'Hide Inactive';
            this.boolVisible1 = true;
            refreshApex(this.inactiveAccount); //Not working when edited a record to inactive
        }
        else if(label === 'Hide Inactive'){
            this.clickedButtonLabel1 = 'Show Inactive';
            this.boolVisible1 = false;
            this.caseNumber = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Child HTML

```
<template>
   <template if:true={childActiveAccount}>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={childActiveAccount}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handlesClick}
                hide-checkbox-column="true"  
                show-row-number-column="true">
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={childInactiveAccount}>
        <div style="height: 300px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="id"
                    data={childInactiveAccount}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowaction={handlesClick}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true" 
                    show-row-number-column="true">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Child JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import {NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation';

const actions = [
    { label: 'View Case', name: 'viewCase' },
    { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
];

const column = [
    { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type : 'button', initialWidth: 250,
    typeAttributes:{label:{fieldName:'Name'},variant:'base'}},
    {
        label: 'Active',
        fieldName: 'Active__c',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    { label: 'More',
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions },
    },
    { label:''

    },

   ];

export default class ChildAccountActiveOrInactive extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @track columns = column;

    @api childActiveAccount;
    @api childInactiveAccount;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `refreshApex`, you need to have the original wire response instead of using `{ data, error }`.

```
getAccountsResponse;
@wire(getAccounts) accDetails(response){
    this.getAccountsResponse = response;
    const { error, data } = response;
    // Rest of original code here
```

This is because the response actually has a "hidden" parameter that `refreshApex` uses to know which wire method to refresh.

Then, to refresh:

```
refreshApex(this.getAccountsResponse);
```

This will call the server, and fire off the `accDetails` response handler when the data is returned.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox